Menu items disappear and reappear when refreshed
I'm using Odoo 14 Community Edition.
I found that some Odoo item menus on the user disappeared when logged in and reappeared when refreshed.
picture 1 Picture 1 shows the menu on user after log in.
The user tries to refresh the homepage and the item menu that should be for the user has appeared.
picture 2 Picture 2 shows the menu that should be there
There is only one user who logs in but I try to delete the cookies and close the browser and when the user tries to log in again, sometimes the menu disappears again
I tried deleting cookies and checking there is no menu hidden in the user settings
